# How do you make every 9th element in Math.random array to be the same element?[javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this bit of code here

```js
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>


var imagesArray = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png","7.png","8.png","9.png","10.png","11.png","12.png","13.png","14.png","15.png","16.png","17.png","18.png","19.png","20.png","21.png" ];

var newArray = new Array(100);

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
if (i % 9 === 0)
{


}
else
{
    newArray[i] = imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length)];
}
}
</script>
```

the idea behind is that i need it so that every 9th number that would be randomly chosen would remain the same, but i have no idea what do i put there so it would work. 
Do you got any advice? 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "remain the same" ?

Comment: Tell me, why do you think you should override Math.random to not be .... random?

Comment: I mean that if math.random for example randoms that 9th element would be 21.png then also 18th and 27th and 36th etc. element would also be 21.png but for the others elements it would be random

Comment: .. so don't use Math.random in the first part of that `if`. But what value to use, then?

Comment: Code for it mate. Write a code that selects things at random but repeats the element in case of 9 - 18 - 27....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of what you can do :

First fill your array with `Math.random()` or whatever you want.

```
imagesArray[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

If you want the value to be the same every 9 elements , use a loop starting at `9` and going through every 9 elements with `i+9`

```
for(var i = 9; i < yourArray.length ; i = i + 9){
    imagesArray[i]  = imagesArray[9];
}
```

Actually you can start the loop at 18 as well

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yzmw853e/)

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a variable outside of `for` loop to store value at first `i % 9 === 0`

```
var newArray = new Array(100), ninth = null;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    newArray[i] = imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length)];
    if (i % 9 === 0 && ninth === null && i === 9) {
      ninth = newArray[i]
    };
    if (i % 9 === 0 && i >= 9) {
      newArray[i] = ninth;
    };      
}
```